# Can I set the Animation frames in Nanosecond not MilliSecond ( Android )

Tags: android, image, animation, gif, frames

Hello as it's explained in title, I want to set the Animation of some frames (Images) in Nanoseconds or Microseconds ( Anything faster than Milliseconsd ) .. I tried to use: 1/10 milliseconds but it's giving errors.. Please help

Comment: You ***really*** need to read this site [help]. Duplicating the same Question 3 times is not the way it works... Having a lot of downvoted, closed, off-topic Questions will [harm your account](http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) in the long run.

Comment: I rolled back the "delete this" edit since the question has an answer with upvotes. Editing the question to a non-question would render the answer out of context. However, you could try to rephrase the question: what are you trying to achieve and why? What have you tried and what is the actual problem there?

Answer (score 2):

Why? The human eye can't recognize more than 24 frames per second, which equates to around 41 milliseconds between each frame. There is no need to animate faster than this.

You can't achieve a precision deeper than a millisecond.

Comment: Too bad, there is nothing that can be done to work around it ?? I am sure there maybe something like this, thank you Gil.

Comment: @Gil you ask why? the key word here is: **human**, OP is writing an app for ET aliens

Comment: If you want the animation to run faster than *as fast as possible*, you might consider skipping frames?